# How to authenticate a user using Cassandra database

Tags: java, cassandra, hector

I want to create a way to authenticate users. In mysql I do:

```
SELECT user_id FROM customers WHERE `username` = 'the_username' AND `password` = 'the_password'
```

If the query doesn't return an empty resultset then user is authorized. Cassandra expects me to know the row key (user_id) upfront. How can I check all rows in a column family for existence of a username and password where I don't know the row key.

I am using Hector api to connect to Cassandra 1.2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some possible solutions:

1. use the username as row key
2. create a secondary index on username

I would use the first one. If username is unique (as I assume), you don't need user_id